# "NameError: uninitialized constant User::MongoMapper" trying to MongoMapper 'Getting Started'

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

Here's my irb session:

```
irb(main):001:0> class User
irb(main):002:1> include MongoMapper::Document
irb(main):003:1> key :name, String
irb(main):004:1> key :age, Integer
irb(main):005:1> many :hobbies
irb(main):006:1> end
NameError: uninitialized constant User::MongoMapper
        from (irb):2
irb(main):007:0>
```

which is right off of http://mongomapper.com/

I'm in windows 7, ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 249.  My gem list includes mongo, mongo_mapper, bson, and bson_ext (among others). I tried 'require'ing 'mongo_mapper' and/or 'mongo', and just got error messages about those 'require's.

I'm sure it's something simple, but as a ruby newbie, I'm stumped.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to

```
require "rubygems"
```

first on 1.8.7.

Ruby 1.9.2 automatically does it for you.

On 1.8.7 you can set an environment variable called "RUBYOPT" to do this for you.
See [here](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3).

Then after you have RubyGems loaded, you can load MongoMapper and everything should work.

```
require "mongo_mapper"
```

Comment: That did it!  I **knew** it was something simple. Thank you!